# While loop in C exits in Repl.it but not when run locally with gcc

Tags: c, struct, while-loop, linked-list

I am fairly new to C but have been asked by my teacher to implement a linked list.

When I ran the code below in Repl.it it works, however when I running it on my machine with gcc on windows, it doesn't exit the while loop.

Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node *newNode(int);
void llAppend(int);
void llPrint(void);

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *ll;

int main(void) {

    llAppend(2);
    llAppend(3);

    llPrint();
}

struct node *newNode(int data) {
  struct node *tmp;

  tmp = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
  tmp->data = data;

  return tmp;
}

void llAppend(int data) {
  struct node *tmp;
  
  if (ll == NULL) {
    ll = newNode(data);
    return;
  }

  tmp = ll;
  while (tmp->next != NULL) {
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
  tmp->next = newNode(data);
}

void llPrint(void) {
  struct node *tmp;

  tmp = ll;
  while (tmp != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", tmp->data);
    tmp = tmp->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Presumably the `malloc()` at repl.it returns zeroed memory, but that's not guaranteed in the real world.  If your code behaves differently on different compilers, assume you've got undefined behaviour somewhere in your code, and fix your code so that you don't.  All bits zero is the worst value for the allocated data to be set to — it can hide inappropriate (missing) initialization very easily.

Comment: Some compilers (seems like the one you used and 'worked' is one of them) initialize things to 0... But It is not a behavior you shouls rely on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It doesn't exit the while loop. Any ideas?

The issue is that you haven't initialized `tmp->next` in `newNode()`. Therefore, in the `while` loop, your code accesses uninitialized memory when it tries to check `tmp->next`.

> When I ran the solution in Repl.it it worked completely fine.

It worked out of luck. There's no knowing what could happen when you access uninitialized memory. It's possible that `tmp->next` happened to be `NULL` so that the code worked in that case.

## How to resolve?

You need to set `tmp->next` to `NULL` in `newNode()` like this:

```
tmp->next = NULL;
```

Also, always check the return value of `malloc`, to ensure that it is not `NULL`.

### Corrected version:

```
struct node *newNode(int data) {
  struct node *tmp;

  tmp = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
  if (tmp == NULL) {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  tmp->data = data;
  tmp->next = NULL;

  return tmp;
}
```

Also, consider using [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org/) and [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), which are powerful tools that can help you debug things like this.

**Side note:** your `main` function is missing a `return` statement -- add `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`

Comment: Thanks for the help code now runs as intended!

Answer (score 1):

In `newNode()` you don't initialise the `next` member.
It could have any value, not necessarily `NULL`.